# How to re-arrange multiple image views in UIView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiimageview, xcode5

I have multiple image views in UIView and if I drag first image view to the new location, others have to rearrange. Is it possible? Suppose you have 1 to 10 images in UIView; first image is dragged to 10th position, now 2nd must be the 1st.

Comment: It is possible, change all the imageView's frame property properly.

Comment: can you please explain this briefly?

Comment: Sounds like a candidate for UICollectionView, where you would use the edit mode. I haven't used this myself, so am unsure if it is exactly what you would want. Worth looking into though.

Comment: @Nick I have already used it in UICollectionView but now i want to use it in UIView.

Comment: @KudoCC Can you explain me the frame property briefly?

Comment: [UIView setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)]; It may be worthwhile you having a look at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html